# how to create two dimensional state array in react js

Tags: reactjs, arrays

i have below table structure in react js

```
  ---------------------------------------------------
    name              age         action
  ---------------------------------------------------
   [errorMsg]        [errorMsg]
   [input box]       [input box]         save
  ----------------------------------------------------
   [errorMsg]        [errorMsg]
   [input box]       [input box]         save
  ----------------------------------------------------
   [errorMsg]        [errorMsg]
   [input box]       [input box]         save
  ----------------------------------------------------
```

when ever i click save, i will validate for emtpy input value, if it is empty then i will display error messge as "Please Enter value"

i have td as

```
<td><span><label className='errorMsg'>{errorMsg[rowIndex, colIndex]}</label></span><input type='text' value={row[column.dataField]} onChange={(e) => column.onChange(e, rowIndex)}></input></td>
```

and errorMsg as 2d array defined as below

```
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(Array(props.data.length).fill(Array(props.columns.length).fill(null)));
```

and on click save, i will validate whether mandatory columns has value or not, if no value , then i show error message above that input field.

```
 const handleSave = (data, index) => {
        props.columns.map((column, colIndex) => {
            if(column.isMandatory){
                if(!data[column.dataField].value ){
                    setErrorMsg((row, rowIdex) => {
                        if(index === rowIdex){
                            row.map((column, i) =>{
                                if(i === colIndex){
                                    return 'Please enter value'
                                }
                                return column;
                            })
                        }
                        return row;
                    })
                }
            }
            return column;
        })
      
    };
```

the issue is, the 2d state array is not initializing properly, and size shows only one dimension with size of 2. how to initialize array with 2d on state variable.